# Text field wider then number field when setting fieldset padding

Tags: html, css

```css
fieldset {
  width: 510px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

*:not(.menu)(fieldset) {
  margin: 1;
  padding: 1;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend style="font-weight: bold">
      Persoonsgegevens
    </legend>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="td1"><label for="Voorletters">Voorletters</label></td>
        <td class="td2"><input name="Voorletters" type="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td1"><label for="Achternaam">Achternaam</label></td>
        <td class="td2"><input name="Achternaam" type="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td1"><label for="Huisnummer">Huisnummer</label></td>
        <td class="td2"><input name="Huisnummer" type="number" /></td>
        <tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="td1"><label for="Postcode">Postcode</label></td>
            <td class="td2"><input name="Postcode" type="text" pattern="^[1-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}" title="Postcode: 1234AA" placeholder="Format: 1234AA" /></td>
          </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'm learning HTML/CSS and working on a form to learn the syntax.
In the form I have a multiple fields like input type="text" input type="number" and type="text" with pattern.

The width of the number and text with pattern fields is smaller then the width of the regular text fields. I've investigated this and solved this by adding the following CSS code:

```
*:not(.menu){
    Margin: 1;
    padding: 0;     
}
```

That worked fine but I'm using a fieldset in which I want to set the padding with the following code:

```
fieldset {
        width: 510px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: black;
        padding-left:1em;
        padding-right: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 2em;
 }
```

This code does not work unless I change the previous code to:

```
*:not(.menu)(fieldset)
    margin: 1;
    padding: 1;     
}
```

but then the text field with pattern and number field aren't the same size as the regular text field anymore.

Anybody any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and copy enough code from the codepen to make a [mcve] - we do NOT need the complete form

Comment: Also, general practice is to keep all CSS props lower case

Comment: I've updated the CSS props and added a snippet editor. I'm new to this so please be patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of all input fields in the css like this:

```css
fieldset {
    width: 510px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    padding-left:1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
 }
 
*:not(.menu)(fieldset){
    margin: 1;
    padding: 1; 
}

input {
  width:200px;  /*<------Set the width here as you desire*/
}
```

```html
<form>   
<fieldset>
<legend style="font-weight: bold"><h3>Persoonsgegevens</h3></legend>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1"><label for="Voorletters">Voorletters</lable></td>
    <td class="td2"><input name="Voorletters" type="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1"><label for="Achternaam">Achternaam</lable></td>
    <td class="td2"><input name="Achternaam" type="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1"><label for="Huisnummer">Huisnummer</lable></td>
    <td class="td2"><input name="Huisnummer" type="number" /></td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1"><label for="Postcode">Postcode</lable></td>
    <td class="td2"><input name="Postcode" type="text" pattern="^[1-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}" title="Postcode: 1234AA" placeholder="Format: 1234AA" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here I made a picture, to show you that they are all the same:

[image]

Comment: If I run that code via the snippet there is still a difference in the size of the fields.

Comment: where do you see that difference? All four of them are identical regarding the width.

Comment: There is a small difference of one or two pixels if you look closely.
The 'Huisnummer' and 'Postcode' fields are a few pixels less wide.

Comment: I can't tell, I edited the answer to show you that...But if u insist, the solution for you is to add the style="width:200px" or something to all of your input fields, and adjust the pixels as u wish.

Comment: I can see it's the same size for you. For me it's not. Perhaps it depends on the browser? I'm using the last version of Chrome.

I did what you suggested and added different px's for the styles that had different width. That solved it. Thank you for putting me on the right track.

Comment: I tested in multiple browsers and they all handle the code differently. That's whats causing the confusion. For now it works fine for Chrome but in the future I'm going the find out how to get it the same for all browsers.